# Numpy does not work in jupyter notebook, but works in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, module

I obtain ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' in my jupyter notebook, but import numpy works in terminal. What is wrong, please?

Comment: Are the notebook and the python interpreter of the same (pip) environment?

Comment: How to find that, please?

Comment: In short: you are using different pythons. Your terminal python is different than the python in your jupyter. One way to see this is to compare `python --version` from the terminal and  `from platform import python_version` followed by `python_version()` from jupyter. Presumably these are different. (If they're the same, then you might have multiple installations of the same python version).

Comment: Yes, they are different - 3.7.3 in jupyter and 3.6.9 in terminal. How to unify them, please?

Comment: Unify them? You don't need to have a single environment, in fact it's very convenient to have many -  it's most of the point of pip and conda. If you want numpy in your notebook, just install it there, for instance `!pip install numpy` in a new cell